# Cloud Function Bug or error in my code : www.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I created a function to send notifications via firebase and I get this error:

```
Error fetching user data (a0ZdYX3IgCbssNNRP2oPZyAAEOt1): { Error: www.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.
    at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:70:23)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:106:51)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:339:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'app/network-timeout',
     message: 'www.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.' } }
```

This is due to me (limitation firebase free?) Or an error on the google server and I just have to wait?

My function (I know the function can be improved in speed but the question is not there, I just want to know if I am the reason for this error) This function sends a notification to users who installed the application x day ago, retrieving the day of the creation of their account and their fcm token is saved in the database :

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificationToNewUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    Date.prototype.sameDay = function(d) {
        return this.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear()
        && this.getDate() === d.getDate()
        && this.getMonth() === d.getMonth();
    }

    var query = admin.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
    var defaultAuth = admin.auth();
    query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var user_id = childSnapshot.key;
            var user_data = childSnapshot.val();

            admin.auth().getUser(user_id)
            .then(function(userRecord) {
                var create_date = userRecord.metadata.createdAt
                var date_now = new Date(Date.now());
                console.log("Creation date:", create_date);
                create_date.setDate(create_date.getDate()+4);
                if (create_date.sameDay(date_now)) {

                    var registrationToken = user_data.fcm_token;

                    const payload = {
                        notification: {
                            body: "blabla",
                            sound: "default"
                        },
                        "data" : {
                            "key" : "XXX",
                            "value" : "playstore"
                        }
                    };

                    var options = {
                        priority: "high",
                        collapseKey: "playstore"
                    };

                    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
                    // registration token with the provided options.
                    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload, options)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error fetching user data ("+user_id+"):", error);
            });
    });
});
response.send("OK");
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending a response to the client ("OK") without waiting for your queries to complete.  You should always use the Promise object returned by asynchronous calls to Realtime Database and other APIs to trigger a response only after those queries are fully complete.  If you don't do this, you will have problems.

As it stands now, your function requires some significant restructuring for it to accumulate all the promises from all the work it's doing, and wait for all of them to complete before sending the final response.